# What are Security Practices for NoSql databases

Tags: nosql, mongodb

I want to know what are the best practices to secure `NoSql` database like `MongoDB`. How is it possible? Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Security.se, you question as formulated here is too broad. Could you refine your question with more details like: what did you already did, what is the architecture of your service (is it direct access to DB via internet, is it a server for an online application, ...), what data do you want to protect (user data, credit card number, ...). As is, this question is very likely to be closed.

Comment: I want to protect user data for my application.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question with the relevant details.

Comment: I want to know tips for securing my database.

Comment: Most like you should just read this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/how-to-secure-a-mongodb-instance?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mongodb i have written this answer

First vulnerability similar to sql injection can be done in mongodb or nosql databases too.
which would be mongodb injection.

Try to run mongodb on different port instead on default 27017 to avoid exposing. 
For official security practices you can always check out
 http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security/

It tell security practices that should be used with mongodb server.

Mongodb Injection :

its fully describes here for php how mongodb injection can take place in phpwebapp if client side data is not filtered properly. Also solution to mongodb injection too

http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2010/07/mongodb-is-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-in-php-at-least/

Mongodb Null byte injection attack

http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/02/mongodb-null-byte-injection-attacks/

This is also a type of attack that is well written on this site , Have a look how 
certain fields in mongo collection can be overwritten using this method can this can be done in any webapp.

Comment: Downvote without a reason?????

Comment: Security by obscurity does not exist.....changing the port does not automatically protect the database.