# Verify that input is a string - is it safe?

Tags: injection, mongodb

I was trying to find out how to prevent MongoDB injections, and I came across [this](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html). So, the vulnerable code here is

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
        db.users.find({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}, function (err, users) { // This line!
            // TODO: handle the rest
        });
});
```

Could I protect against a MongoDB injection by verifying that the `POST` body username and password are both strings, and not objects?

Are there any other ways to inject data into a MongoDB database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to secure a MongoDB instance?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7610/how-to-secure-a-mongodb-instance)

Comment: @crovers that doesn't answer the question - does verifying that the input is a string sanitize inputs completely

Answer (score 1):

Yes, verifying the input is a string will sanitize it.

MongoDB doesn't parse strings, only JSON. A common attack on MongoDB is:

```
{"$gte":""}
```

When put in a query, this will return all objects. An attacker can pass this as a parameter, and some parsers will automatically expand it into an object, which will make your JSON look like this

```
{
    username: "root",
    password: { $gte: ""}
}
```

When this find command is run, it'll return the root user even though a password wasn't supplied.
(Note: Do not verify passwords like this)

Now here's an example where we ensure that the input is a string

```
{
    username: "root",
    password: "{\"$gte\":\"\"}"
}
```

As you can see, there's no injection, and we're literally looking for that password.